# Getting compgen to include slashes on directories when looking for files

Tags: bash, autocomplete, bash-completion

I'd like to get the following behavior from my custom completion

Given

```
$ mkdir foo
$ touch foo faz/bar faz/baz
```

I'd like to get this

```
$ foo -u <tab><tab> =>
foo faz/

$ foo -u fa<tab><tab> =>
foo -u faz/

$ foo -u faz/<tab><tab> =>
bar baz
```

I assumed that `compgen -f f` would output `foo faz/`, but it outputs `foo faz` which doesn't help me much.

Do I need to post-process the output or is there some magic combination of options to compgen that work?

Answer (score 29):

I ran into the same problem. Here's the workaround I'm using:

1. Register the completion function with `-o default`, e.g., `complete -o default -F _my_completion`.
2. When you want to complete a filename, just set `COMPREPLY=()` and let Readline take over (that's what the `-o default` does).

There's a potential problem with this -- you might be using `COMPREPLY=()` to deny completion where it's not appropriate, and now that won't work anymore. In Bash 4.0 and above, you can work around this using `compopt` as follows:

1. At the top of your completion function, always run `compopt +o default`. This disables Readline filename completion when `COMPREPLY` is empty.
2. When you want to complete a filename, use `compopt -o default; COMPREPLY=()`. In other words, enable Readline filename completion only when you need it.

I haven't figured out a full workaround for pre-4.0 Bash, but I have something that works well enough for me. I can describe this if anyone really cares, but hopefully these older Bash versions will soon fall out of common use anyway.

Comment: Thanks!! This helped me. Interestingly the plus option (`compopt +o`) seems not to be documented in the [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion-Builtins.html)..

Comment: Glad it helped. BTW, here is a thread where the author of Bash tells me that my approach above is pretty much the way to do it (unfortunately): http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2013-10/msg00002.html

Answer (score 10):

Previous answers require bash 4, or aren't composable with other compgen-based completions for the same command. The following solution doesn't require compopt (so it works with bash 3.2) and it is composable (for example you can easily add additional filtering to only match certain file extensions). Skip to the bottom if impatient.

---

You can test compgen by running it directly on the command line:

```
compgen -f -- $cur
```

where `$cur` is the word you would've typed so far during interactive tab-completion.

If I'm in a directory that has a file `afile.py` and a sub-directory `adir`, and `cur=a` then the above command shows the following:

```
$ cur=a
$ compgen -f -- $cur
adir
afile
```

Note that `compgen -f` shows files *and* directories. `compgen -d` shows only directories:

```
$ compgen -d -- $cur
adir
```

Adding `-S /` will add a trailing slash to every result:

```
$ compgen -d -S / -- $cur
adir/
```

Now, we can try listing all files and all directories:

```
$ compgen -f -- $cur; compgen -d -S / -- $cur
adir
afile.py
adir/
```

Note that there's nothing stopping you from calling compgen more than once! In your completion script you would use it like this:

```
cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -f -- "$cur"; compgen -d -S / -- "$cur") )
```

Unfortunately, this still doesn't give us the behaviour that we want, because if you type `ad<TAB>` you have two possible completions: `adir` and `adir/`. So `ad<TAB>` will complete to `adir`, at which point you still have to type in the `/` to disambiguate.

What we need now is a function that will return all files but no directories. Here it is:

```
$ grep -v -F -f <(compgen -d -P '^' -S '$' -- "$cur") \
>     <(compgen -f -P '^' -S '$' -- "$cur") |
>     sed -e 's/^\^//' -e 's/\$$//'
afile.py
```

Let's break it down:

- `grep -f file1 file2` means show the lines in file2 that match any of the patterns in file1.
- `-F` means the patterns in file1 must match exactly (as a substring); they aren't regular expressions.
- `-v` means invert the match: Only show lines that *aren't* in file1.
- `<(...)` is bash [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html). It allows you to run any command in the places where a file is expected.

So we're telling grep: here's a list of files -- remove any that match this list of directories.

```
$ grep -v -F -f <(compgen -d -P '^' -S '$' -- "$cur") \
>     <(compgen -f -P '^' -S '$' -- "$cur")
^afile.py$
```

I've added beginning and end markers with compgen's `-P ^` and `-S '$'` because grep's `-F` does substring matching and we don't want to remove a filename like `a-file-with-adir-in-the-middle` just because its middle part matched a directory's name. Once we have the list of files we remove those markers with sed.

Now we can write a function that does what we want:

```
# Returns filenames and directories, appending a slash to directory names.
_mycmd_compgen_filenames() {
    local cur="$1"

    # Files, excluding directories:
    grep -v -F -f <(compgen -d -P ^ -S '$' -- "$cur") \
        <(compgen -f -P ^ -S '$' -- "$cur") |
        sed -e 's/^\^//' -e 's/\$$/ /'

    # Directories:
    compgen -d -S / -- "$cur"
}
```

You use it like this:

```
_mycmd_complete() {
    local cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
    COMPREPLY=( $(_mycmd_compgen_filenames "$cur") )
}
complete -o nospace -F _mycmd_complete mycmd
```

Note that `-o nospace` means you don't get a space after a directory's `/`. For normal files we added a space at the end with sed.

One nice thing about having this in a separate function is that it's easy to test! For example here's an automated test:

```
diff -u <(printf "afile.py \nadir/\n") <(_mycmd_compgen_filenames "a") \
    || { echo "error: unexpected completions"; exit 1; }
```

Comment: I used it as:
    COMPREPLY=( $(_my_compgen_filenames "${cur}") ) 
but the space substitution in sed doesn't seem to happen. I think the sed works as expected, but the command substitution in my usage causes it to be gobbled (?).  Any clues?

Comment: @stellarhopper what are your symptoms -- when you press TAB it doesn't add a space to the end of a filename that is unique? What happens if you run `_my_compgen_filenames "whatever-you-typed-before-pressing-tab"` -- does it have a space at the end or not? Are you using `complete` with `-o nospace`?

Comment: Correct, it doesn't add a space at the end of a unique filename. If I run the function manually at the prompt, it it does add the space correctly.. I do have -o nospace, but I think I need that? How else do I stop it from adding a space for every completion?

Comment: @stellarhopper yes you need `-o nospace`. What version of bash are you using? I tested this with bash 4.3.46.

Comment: I'm on 4.3.42 (from Fedora 24)

Comment: This answer is the **most configurable** answer I've found on the SE network. I was able to massage it into suggesting files and directories, including in subdirectories, of a specific directory. **Thank you!**

Answer (score 5):

This behaviour is influenced by the **readline** variable `mark-directories` (and the related `mark-symlinked-directories`). I believe the variable should be set **on** for `complete` to print a trailing slash on directory names (the default in bash v3.00.16). Seemingly the related behaviour of `compgen` doesn't append a slash to directory names :-\

Set the value of `mark-directories` alternately to `on` and `off` then retry your test:-

```
bind 'set mark-directories on'
bind 'set mark-directories off'
```

To make the change permanent for future invocations of `bash`, add the following to your INPUTRC file, commonly `~/.inputrc`:-

```
$if Bash
# append '/' to dirnames
set mark-directories on
$endif
```

The tip to set readline variables in the current shell was found here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/27545. I didn't determine how to test the current value of a readline variable.

### Additional Ideas

*Perhaps only academic interest...*

Create a list of directory names only and append a slash:-

```
compgen -d -S / f
```

Comment: Hm, I think it's already set: bind -V|grep mark-directories => mark-directories is set to `on'. Tried switching it but no luck as far as I can tell.

Comment: @trygvis You are correct, I see your behaviour when using `compgen`. I initially performed my testing by defining a compspec with `complete` which did generate the trailing slash. Hmmm, don't have a further answer at this stage, though I've corrected the above text.

Comment: I was getting a similar problem on the Mac, `mark-directories` was `on`, still got the problem. After I set `mark-symlinked-directories` it worked. It just happened that I was tabbing frequently into a dropbox-symlinked directory, and apparently it doesn't add the `/` even in deeper parts of the path that are not symlinks themselves.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `-o filenames` option passed to the `complete` directive. As long as the contents of `COMPREPLY` are valid paths the slash will be appended as appropriate while still adding a space after completion of non-directory matches. (Works on bash 3.2.)

```sh
_cmd() {
  COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -f -- "$cur" ))
  COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -A file -- "$cur" ))  # same thing
}

complete -o filenames -F _cmd cmd
```

See `info -n "(bash)Programmable Completion Builtins"`:

> complete
>
> > ...
> >         -o COMP-OPTION
> >     ...
> >
> > > ```
> > >      filenames
> > >            Tell Readline that the compspec generates filenames, so
> > >            it can perform any filename-specific processing (like
> > >            adding a slash to directory names or suppressing
> > >            trailing spaces).  This option is intended to be used
> > >            with shell functions specified with `-F'.
> > > ```

And:

> ```
> -A ACTION
> ```
>
> > ...
> >               'file'
> >
> > > ```
> > >            File names.  May also be specified as -f.
> > > ```

Note: `compgen` and `complete` have the same arguments.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
_my_completion() { 
  compopt -o nospace 
  COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -S "/" -d "${COMP_WORDS[$COMP_CWORD]}") )
}

complete -F _my_completion foo
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to continue using tab after the directory was completed; here's the complete solution:

```
cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -S "/" -d -- ${cur}) ); 
compopt -o nospace;
```

first add a trailing slash to the answer. Then run the `compopt -o nospace` command to remove the trailing space. Now if you have only `foo/bar` in your directory, two tabs will suffice to type them!