# How to enable default file completion in bash

Tags: bash

Say I have a command named "foo" that takes one argument (either "encrypt" or "decrypt") and then a list of files.  I want to write a bash completion script that helps with the first argument and then enables standard file completion for the others.  The closest I've been able to come is this:

```
complete -F _foo foo

function _foo()
{
    local cmds cur
    if [ $COMP_CWORD -eq 1 ]
    then
        cur="${COMP_WORDS[1]}"
        cmds=("encrypt decrypt")
        COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "${cmds}" -- ${cur}) )
    else
        COMPREPLY=($(compgen -f ${COMP_WORDS[${COMP_CWORD}]} ) )
    fi
}
```

This does the first argument correctly and will chose a filename from the current directory for the subsequent ones.  But say the current directory contains a subdirectory bar that contains a file baz.txt.  After typing ba-TAB-TAB, completion results in "bar " (space after the "r") and is ready to choose the next argument.  What I want is the standard bash completion, where the result is "bar/" (no space after the slash), ready to choose a file in the subdirectory.  Is there any way to get that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The bash documentation can be a little enigmatic. The simplest solution is to alter the completion function binding:

```
complete -o filenames -F _foo foo
```

This means the function returns filenames (including directories), and special handling of the results is enabled.

(IMHO the documentation doesn't make it clear that this effectively post-processes `COMPREPLY[]` as set by your completion function; and that some of the `-o` options, that one included, when applied to `compgen` appear to have no effect.)

You can get closer to normal bash behaviour by using:

```
 complete -o filenames -o bashdefault -F _foo foo
```

that gets you "~" completion back.

There are two problems with the above however:

- if you have a directory named "encrypt" or "decrypt" then the expansion of your keywords will grow a trailing "/"
- `$VARIABLE` expansion won't work, `$` will become `\$` to better match a filename with a `$`. Similarly  `@host` expansion won't work.

The only way that I have found to deal with this is to process the `compgen` output, and not rely on the "filenames" post-processing:

```
_foo()
{
    local cmds cur ff
    if (($COMP_CWORD == 1))
    then
        cur="${COMP_WORDS[1]}"
        cmds="encrypt decrypt"
        COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "$cmds" -- "$cur"))
        COMPREPLY=( "${COMPREPLY[@]/%/ }" )   # add trailing space to each
    else
        # get all matching files and directories
        COMPREPLY=($(compgen -f  -- "${COMP_WORDS[$COMP_CWORD]}"))

        for ((ff=0; ff<${#COMPREPLY[@]}; ff++)); do
            [[ -d ${COMPREPLY[$ff]} ]] && COMPREPLY[$ff]+='/'
            [[ -f ${COMPREPLY[$ff]} ]] && COMPREPLY[$ff]+=' '
        done
    fi
}

complete -o bashdefault -o default -o nospace -F _foo foo
```

(I also removed the superfluous array for `cmd` in the above, and made `compgen` more robust and handle spaces or leading dashes in filenames.)

The downsides now are that when you get the intermediate completion list (i.e. when you hit <kbd>tab</kbd> twice to show multiple matches) you won't see a trailing / on directories, and since `nospace` is enabled the `~ $ @` expansions won't grow a space to cause them to be accepted.

In short, I do not believe you can trivially mix-and-match your own completion and the full bash completion behaviour.

Comment: `${COMPREPLY[@]/%/ }` adds a space?  Bash is a truely ug*cough*tiful language.

Answer (score 25):

I know this is a little late, but I have found a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19062943/108105

Basically, you use `complete -o bashdefault -o default`, and when you want to revert to the default bash completion you set `COMPREPLY=()`. Here's an example:

```
complete -o bashdefault -o default -F _foo foo
_foo() {
    local cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
    if (( $COMP_CWORD == 1 )); then
        COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W 'encrypt decrypt' -- "$cur") )
    else
        COMPREPLY=()
    fi
}
```

Comment: +1 Very neat. It reverts to readline defaults not bash though, not that it affects the OP, but you loose bashdefault completions ($, ~ , @). I think `compopt -o bashdefault` (bash-4.0) can help there.