# How to extend bash completion in other directory?

Tags: bash, autocomplete, bash-completion

I'm learning about bash completion. I'm able to list the content of only current directory. Here is my code:

```
   _foo()
   {
       local cur prev opts
       COMPREPLY=()
       cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
       prev="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}"

       opts="push pull"
       OUTPUT=" $(ls) "

      case "${prev}" in
          push)
              COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "--in --out" -- ${cur}) )
              return 0
              ;;
          --in)
              COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "$OUTPUT" -- ${cur}) )
              return 0
              ;;
      esac

        COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "${opts}" -- ${cur}))
        return 0
  }
  complete -F _foo foo
```

It's output is:

```
$ foo push --in[TAB]
file1.txt file2.txt foo  ;; content of pwd
```

But when I do this:

```
$ foo push --in ~[TAB]
```

It's not working.
So I want to know how to do bash completion in different directory (not only in *pwd*)? Thanks.

Comment: Oh they are actually not in script. These are just because of Vim editor. And I copied this script from there so line number also copied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `-f` to match filenames :

```
#!/bin/bash
_foo()    {
       local cur prev opts
       COMPREPLY=()
       cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
       prev="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}"
       opts="push pull"

       case "${prev}" in
          push)
              COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "--in --out" -- ${cur}) )
              return 0
              ;;
          --in)
              COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -f ${cur}) )
              return 0
              ;;
      esac

      COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "${opts}" -- ${cur}))
      return 0   
}

complete -F _foo foo
```

However it seems that it doesn't work for `~` alone but `$ foo push --in ~/[TAB]` works and all other directories
This solution wont include slash to look for file in directory : `$ foo push --in /etc[TAB]` will give `foo push --in /etc`  and not `foo push --in /etc/`

The following post solves that problem using default mode :
[Getting compgen to include slashes on directories when looking for files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12933362/getting-compgen-to-include-slashes-on-directories-when-looking-for-files/19062943#19062943)

> default
>
> Use Readline’s default filename completion if the compspec generates no matches.

So you can use :

```
#!/bin/bash
_foo()
   {
       local cur prev opts
       COMPREPLY=()
       cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
       prev="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}"

       opts="push pull"
       OUTPUT=" $(ls) "

      case "${prev}" in
          push)
              COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "--in --out" -- ${cur}) )
              return 0
              ;;
          --in)
              COMPREPLY=()
              return 0
              ;;
          --port)
              COMPREPLY=("")
              return 0
              ;;
      esac

        COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "${opts}" -- ${cur}))
        return 0
  }
  complete -o default -F _foo foo
```

Or setting to default mode when you need to like this post : https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/149398/146783

Comment: This is good. But What If I don't want to do anything in particular case. Suppose there is argument --port, And I want to take it from keyboard. It should be like this
`$ foo push --port[TAB]`
;; Auto completion should stop, no result.
It indicate user to pass --port value from keyboard. 
But by your answer, It will be 
`$ foo push --port[TAB]`
;; content of pwd
So is there any way to specify that, we don't default result in these cases?

Comment: But that's not working. 
`$ foo push --in[TAB] bash: compopt: command not found`
This is error message which I got.

Comment: Did you source the file in bash_completion.d ? try to add `#!/bin/bash` at the top to be sure it uses the right bash. If your bash is not in `/bin/bash` replace with the right bash location (`which bash`)

Comment: this wont include slash to look for subdirectories if you do that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116908/discussion-between-rishi-kant-and-bertrand-martel).